# Why can't I login to this site using the Requests module?

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to make an API for a pastebin/file upload site. The problem is, I can't seem to login to an account so I can add support for authorized pastes/uploads. [This](http://sharefa.st/) is the website.

Here's what I have so far. I do not know why it's not working.

```
import requests

sess = requests.Session()
sess.post('http://sharefa.st/login', data={'username': username, 'password': password, 'remember_me': 'true', 'login': 'Sign In'})

print sess.get('http://sharefa.st/vault').text #secret page for logged-in people.
```

Comment: What exactly is not working?

Comment: RickyA: I can't log in.

Comment: What does requests say?

Comment: Er... requests returns the login page's HTML source. No errors or anything.

Comment: Did you check response body? Maybe your login data was incorrect? Otherwise,

Comment: @FallenAngel: Response body returns HTML content of the login page. Login data is correct. Post parameters are correct on my browser.

Comment: I mean, did you view response body in a browser? Maybe you got a login error?

Comment: @FallenAngel Weirdly enough, the response body for the post request in my browser is this. http://i.imgur.com/ssZdvLM.png My login details in my script are correct.

Comment: Copy your text body and save it as html. Then examine it. I checked it with a random login data and response body have `<div class="error_bar error">Sorry, but your username does not match that password.</div>`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48847/discussion-between-brandon-jackson-and-fallenangel)

Answer (score 0):

If you first try to print the status code, you can see what is going on:

```
print sess.status_code
```

The list of possible codes is [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) and the requests documentation is [here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#response-status-codes).